# IF statement in sql searching for a string

Tags: mysql

hello i am trying to make a mysql query to find if there is a specific string on a table in a mysql database and if it doesnt exist add it. but my query doesnt seems to work and i cant find anything on the net. (maybe its not posible to do this kind of thing in mysql or maybe i am just doing it wrong)

```
IF ( SELECT word FROM words WHERE word = 'hello' ) THEN
BEGIN select * from word;
END;
ELSE
BEGIN INSERT INTO TABLE word VALUES ('hello');
END;
END IF;
```

thx in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `INSERT` with an `EXISTS` clause:

```
INSERT INTO yourTable (word)
SELECT 'word' FROM dual
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM yourTable WHERE word = 'word');
```

You may want to also research things like unique constraints (e.g. a unique constraint on the `word` column), or upserts, which can do an update if it finds that a record already exists.

Comment: @Nick Yes, my MacBook Air auto correct got the better of me...again

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try with something like this:

```
INSERT INTO `tablename` (`word`) 
VALUES ('hello')
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM `words`
    WHERE `word` = 'hello'
);
```